# sort 2 dependent dart arrays

Tags: flutter, dart

I have got 2 arrays

```
ids=[GEORGE, RUSTY, RIYAZAT, JAMES PAWNED];
avgscore=[10, 13, 3, 40];
```

I want the result array to be sorted in descending order wrt marks scored
and both the arrays should be sorted accordingly, the result should be like this

```
ids should be sorted as [40, 13, 10, 3];
avgscore should be sorted as [JAMES PAWNED, RUSTY, GEORGE, RIYAZAT];
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65019483/1953515

Comment: page not found?

Comment: It was there before which was the identical problem with a solution. I guess it was removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make a class which binds your two data together. Then it is easy to sort based on the `avgscore` value:

```
class Person {
  final String id;
  final int avgscore;
  Person(this.id, this.avgscore);

  @override
  String toString() => '$id = $avgscore';
}

void main() {
  var ids = ['GEORGE', 'RUSTY', 'RIYAZAT', 'JAMES PAWNED'];
  var avgscore = [10, 13, 3, 40];

  final persons = List.generate(ids.length, (i) => Person(ids[i], avgscore[i]));
  print(persons); // [GEORGE = 10, RUSTY = 13, RIYAZAT = 3, JAMES PAWNED = 40]

  persons.sort((p1, p2) => p2.avgscore.compareTo(p1.avgscore));

  print(persons); // [JAMES PAWNED = 40, RUSTY = 13, GEORGE = 10, RIYAZAT = 3]

  // If you need to split the values into two arrays again
  ids = persons.map((p) => p.id).toList();
  avgscore = persons.map((p) => p.avgscore).toList();

  print(ids); // [JAMES PAWNED, RUSTY, GEORGE, RIYAZAT]
  print(avgscore); // [40, 13, 10, 3]
}
```

Comment: but there is one issue, that I had with another algorithm as well. I used bubble sort on the avg score, and the same operation on the ids array, although the avgscore was always descending, the ids array sometimes prints the wrong result. and it's the same with your algorithm aswell.

Comment: Well, you need to come with an example which can reproduce that problem. My guess would be you have a problem with the order of `ids` and `avgscore` in the beginning (both are statically set in my example but I am guessing they comes from somewhere in your code).

Comment: no i realised that this error is from firebase, it gives morphed arrays sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

personally I think that it would be easier for you if you work with a list of Maps specially if you're planning to have more data and not just 4 in your list

here's an example of what working with a map would look like

```
void sortMap() {
  var temp= { 
  "GEORGE":10, 
  "RUSTY":13, 
  "RIYAZAT":3, 
  "JAMES PAWNED":40
  };

  temp = SplayTreeMap.from(
  temp, (key1, key2) => temp[key1].compareTo(temp[key2]));
  print(temp);
}
```

Comment: You should really not create a `SplayTreeMap` where the given `compare` method are dependent on outside factors like elements in a map outside of the `SplayTreeMap`. Your problem is that if you are going to later introduce another element to the `SplayTreeMap` which are not part of firstly created `temp` Map, then it will not work as expected.

Comment: Also, `SplayTreeMap` is a automatically sorted based on the `key` and not `value`. So if you are later changing the `value` of a given `key` it will no longer stay sorted.

Comment: @julemand101 Thank you for your Help, I really appreciate it, Thank you so much.